# Formula to Divide Total of Columns and Format Result Not Valid

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following SQL code below that is returning an error message stating that the `AvgPYs` column is not valid. This is also impacting my `Auth` column. Is there an issue with my formula? Any help is appreciated.

```
SELECT [tblCeiling].[Proj Code], [tblCeiling].[Act Code], [tblCeiling].[Cost Ctr], [tblCeiling].[Date], [tblCeiling].[Ref2], [tblCeiling].[Analyst], [tblCeiling].[Type], [tblCeiling].[B or O], [tblCeiling].[Jul], [tblCeiling].[Aug], 
                  [tblCeiling].[Sep], [tblCeiling].[Oct], [tblCeiling].[Nov], [tblCeiling].[Dec], [tblCeiling].[Jan], [tblCeiling].[Feb], [tblCeiling].[Mar], [tblCeiling].[Apr], [tblCeiling].[May], [tblCeiling].[Jun], [tblCeiling].[Perm], [tblCeiling].[Temp], [tblCeiling].[LimitedTerm], 
                  [tblCeiling].[LTDate], [tblCeiling].[Sal_Rate], [tblCeiling].[New], [Perm] + [Temp] + [LimitedTerm] AS Monthly, Format(([tblCeiling].[Jul] + [tblCeiling].[Aug] + [tblCeiling].[Sep] + [tblCeiling].[Oct] + [tblCeiling].[Nov] + [tblCeiling].[Dec] + [tblCeiling].[Jan] +
                  [tblCeiling].[Feb] + [tblCeiling].[Mar] + [tblCeiling].[Apr] + [tblCeiling].[May] + [tblCeiling].[Jun]) / 12, '0.0####') AS AvgPYs, 
                  ((([Sal_Rate] * [AvgPYs]) * 1000) / 1000) AS Auth, [Dollar Adj] + [Auth] AS Budget, [tblCeiling].[Import], [tblCeiling].[Dollar Adj], [tblCeiling].[OngoingOrOneTime], [tblCeiling].[OneTimeEndingDate]
FROM     (SELECT DISTINCT *
                  FROM      [tblactcode]) AS [tblactcode] RIGHT JOIN
                      (SELECT DISTINCT *
                       FROM      [tblCeiling]) AS [tblCeiling] ON [tblactcode].[Act Code] = [tblCeiling].[Act Code]
WHERE  ((([tblCeiling].[Jul]) = iif([jul] IS NULL, 0, [jul])) AND (([tblCeiling].[Aug]) = iif([aug] IS NULL, 0, [aug])) AND (([tblCeiling].[Sep]) = iif([sep] IS NULL, 0, [sep])) AND (([tblCeiling].[Oct]) = iif([oct] IS NULL, 0, [oct])) AND (([tblCeiling].[Nov]) = iif([nov] IS NULL,
                   0, [nov])) AND (([tblCeiling].[Dec]) = iif([dec] IS NULL, 0, [dec])) AND (([tblCeiling].[Jan]) = iif([jan] IS NULL, 0, [jan])) AND (([tblCeiling].[Feb]) = iif([feb] IS NULL, 0, [feb])) AND (([tblCeiling].[Mar]) = iif([mar] IS NULL, 0, [mar])) AND (([tblCeiling].[Apr]) 
                  = iif([apr] IS NULL, 0, [apr])) AND (([tblCeiling].[May]) = iif([may] IS NULL, 0, [may])) AND (([tblCeiling].[Jun]) = iif([jun] IS NULL, 0, [jun])) AND (([tblCeiling].[Import]) = 0))
ORDER BY [tblCeiling].[Proj Code], [tblCeiling].[Cost Ctr], [tblCeiling].[Date]
```

[image: invalidName]

Here is the specific line I'm referring to:

```
Format(([tblCeiling].[Jul] + [tblCeiling].[Aug] + [tblCeiling].[Sep] + [tblCeiling].[Oct] + [tblCeiling].[Nov] + [tblCeiling].[Dec] + [tblCeiling].[Jan] +
                  [tblCeiling].[Feb] + [tblCeiling].[Mar] + [tblCeiling].[Apr] + [tblCeiling].[May] + [tblCeiling].[Jun]) / 12, '0.0####') AS AvgPYs,
```

Comment: Which brackets don't match? Also, if I can't access a calculated column in the same scope, wouldn't the Monthly column also throw an error?

Comment: Don't use images for errors... just the actual text is all we need.

Comment: Some people have requested images in the past so I've always just included them.

Comment: They are wrong. The site rules say no images... except for UI design.

Comment: You're not attempting to make use of the "Monthly" column anywhere else... hence no error for that one.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you. It's because I'm trying to access it to calculate the Auth column. I'm used to programming in Access, and these types of things don't usually throw an error (from my experience).

Comment: I would also be highly suspicious of needing to use `distinct` in your queries. That is often a sign of a fudge.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is certainly a code smell, it's usually an indication of poorly thought out design or poor joining strategy. Use `ISNULL()` function instead of `IIF(... IS NULL` Styling: use table aliases, don't quote column names with brackets `[]` unless they must be so. Use whitespace, it's free

Comment: @Charlieface Thank you for your reply. This is interesting as I see lots of people using `DISTINCT`. Are there only certain situations where it's acceptable? Should I be looking to redesign parts of my database so it shouldn't be used?

Comment: Put it this way: it is basically the same as `GROUP BY` all columns, and you need to question the need to do that. Normally, you would group by some columns and aggregate others. If you are just getting distinct values because you have duplicates, you need to think first about why you have those duplicates. Is it because you have duplicate rows in the source table, fix your design. Or if your joins are duplicating rows then think carefully about what you are joining on and whether you need an `APPLY` or row-numbering join instead

Comment: `((([Sal_Rate] * [AvgPYs]) * 1000) / 1000)` Why? You've picked up a lot of bad habits that will be difficult to unlearn. Suggest you spend some time re-learning how to write code generally. At the most basic level, all those square brackets and little formatting make your code very difficult to read. Code reviews should be in your future - something that is off-topic for this site.

Comment: @BobtheBuilder with regard to your latest question, now deleted. You just plain didn't give us enough information to go on. There is only one circumstance I know where SSMS might reformat a query, and that is when you use the view designer (which its recommended never to do anyway). You didn't say at all what you were doing with the query at the time it got reformatted (were you running it, saving it, not many other options I can think of), and you didn't post the links to the similar problems you mentioned in your last comment.

Comment: @BobtheBuilder you need to assume you are explaining the problem to someone who has no knowledge of your setup nor how you do things and go through step by step on how to reproduce the issue i.e. a [mre] (exactly like you would want if a client was reporting a bug in your system back to you - the good old "it didn't work"  isn't helpful).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific issue you have run into is attempting to use a calculation in the same scope you are calculating it - which isn't possible. You can only access a calculated value in an outer query.

Or a neat solution is to use `CROSS APPLY` which allows you to reuse a calculation as follows. In general this is done as:

```
select -- existing columns before AvgPYs
  , AvgPYs
  -- , some formula which depends on AvgPYs 
from (
    -- existing query
) C -- C is an acceptable short alias for Ceiling
cross apply (
    values (formula)
) X (AvgPYs)
```

In your case I think the following is correct:

```
SELECT C.[Proj Code], C.[Act Code], C.[Cost Ctr], C.[Date], C.[Ref2], C.[Analyst], C.[Type], C.[B or O], C.[Jul], C.[Aug] 
    , C.[Sep], C.[Oct], C.[Nov], C.[Dec], C.[Jan], C.[Feb], C.[Mar], C.[Apr], C.[May], C.[Jun], C.[Perm], C.[Temp], C.[LimitedTerm]
    , C.[LTDate], C.[Sal_Rate], C.[New], [Perm] + [Temp] + [LimitedTerm] AS Monthly
    , X.AvgPYs 
    , Y.Auth
    , [Dollar Adj] + Y.Auth AS Budget, C.[Import], C.[Dollar Adj], C.[OngoingOrOneTime], C.[OneTimeEndingDate]
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT *
    FROM [tblactcode]
) AS AC
RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT *
    FROM [tblCeiling]
) AS C ON AC.[Act Code] = C.[Act Code]
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES (Format((C.[Jul] + C.[Aug] + C.[Sep] + C.[Oct] + C.[Nov] + C.[Dec] + C.[Jan] +
    C.[Feb] + C.[Mar] + C.[Apr] + C.[May] + C.[Jun]) / 12, '0.0####'))
) AS X (AvgPYs)
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES (((([Sal_Rate] * X.AvgPYs) * 1000) / 1000))
) Y (Auth)
WHERE (((C.[Jul]) = iif([jul] IS NULL, 0, [jul])) AND ((C.[Aug]) = iif([aug] IS NULL, 0, [aug])) AND ((C.[Sep]) = iif([sep] IS NULL, 0, [sep])) AND ((C.[Oct]) = iif([oct] IS NULL, 0, [oct])) AND ((C.[Nov]) = iif([nov] IS NULL,
    0, [nov])) AND ((C.[Dec]) = iif([dec] IS NULL, 0, [dec])) AND ((C.[Jan]) = iif([jan] IS NULL, 0, [jan])) AND ((C.[Feb]) = iif([feb] IS NULL, 0, [feb])) AND ((C.[Mar]) = iif([mar] IS NULL, 0, [mar])) AND ((C.[Apr]) 
    = iif([apr] IS NULL, 0, [apr])) AND ((C.[May]) = iif([may] IS NULL, 0, [may])) AND ((C.[Jun]) = iif([jun] IS NULL, 0, [jun])) AND ((C.[Import]) = 0)
)
ORDER BY C.[Proj Code], C.[Cost Ctr], C.[Date];
```

Note: A key purpose of a table alias is to have a **short** reference to the table. See how much easier it is to read with shorter aliases.

Comment: Thank you. I've never use cross apply before so I'll definitely have to try it more often, and yes, you are absolutely right. I'm bad about not using aliases. Also, would a stored procedure accomplish the same goal as cross apply? Finally, what could using distinct be a sign of? I've used distinct a lot so I'm curious how I should avoid it.

Comment: @BobtheBuilder a stored procedure is a container for SQL statements... so you will still be running exactly the same SQL within your SP.

Comment: I'm familiar with how aliases work, but I actually haven't seen the parenthetical component before. Is this how a name is assigned to the derived table's column? I don't know what the syntax would be called and honestly couldn't find much online. Also, when attempting to execute the SQL, I am receiving the error "Invalid column name 'Auth.'"

Comment: Also, what's the purpose of using VALUES with FORMAT? I'm familiar with using it in conjunction with an INSERT INTO statement, but not with this function. I'm assuming it's similar to the VALUE function for VBA, which you can use to extract the values from formulas.

Comment: @BobtheBuilder you're better off reading the documentation than asking me to explain these concepts in tiny comments e.g. [values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: "I'm familiar with how aliases work, but I actually haven't seen the parenthetical component before" I don't know what you mean by this? I've just shorted your table aliases, i.e. you used `[tblCeiling]` I used `C`.

Comment: `I am receiving the error "Invalid column name 'Auth.'"` - well is exactly the same as the original problem, attempting to use a calculated column in the same scope. Just move that to a second `cross apply`.

Comment: I've read the documentation but wasn't able to figure it out. I'll research some more. I was referring to X (AvgPYs). Thanks for your help though. Appreciate it!

Comment: When using values as a derived table you need to name (alias) it, and the columns in order to be able to reference it elsewhere. Same as for a CTE.